# How can i Update the status of field with a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

This is my example code:

```
create trigger MyTrigger on myTable
after update
as
begin
   set nocount on;
   update talleres set status='active' where FirstDate=getdate()
end
go


create trigger MyTrigge2 on MyTable
for update
as
begin
   declare @d DATETIME=getdate();
   set nocount on;
   update talleres set status='Active' where FirstDate=format(@d,'MM/dd/YYYY')
end
go
```

Comment: What data type is `FirstDate`?

Answer (score 3):

Please consider creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) for this and any future questions you create.  As it is, your question is extremely imprecise and open to a lot of interpretation about what the actual problem is you are trying to solve.

Aside from that, there are several issues I see immediately.

SQL Server DML triggers use the "special" virtual tables, `inserted` and `deleted`, as placeholders containing the rows that will have been modified.  You should use them in your statements to only update the affected rows.  Microsoft Docs has a great article about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

An example for your first trigger:

```
create trigger MyTrigger on myTable
after update
as
begin
   set nocount on;
   update talleres 
   from talleres t inner join inserted i on t.talleres_id = i.talleres_id
   set status='active' 
   where FirstDate=getdate()
end
go
```

In the above example, I'm assuming you have a column that uniquely identifies rows in the talleres table and the MyTable table.

The `WHERE firstdate = getdate()` construct is likely going to be problematic since `getdate()` returns a very precise value that is perhaps unlikely to match any rows in `talleres`.